# Shows object in console but when try to fetch object value then shows object null error

Tags: reactjs, redux

When I try to `console.log(user.user)` in `dashboard component( a functional component)` then it console output is `Array [ {…} ]` and expending this look like this [image].

But when I try to get email from this object like `console.log(user[0].email)` then I get `user is null` error on screen.

User is set in redux reducer and I am serving it from mapDispatchToProps. I could not find what is issue.

Comment: shouldn't it be user.user[0].email as you earlier you mentioned you are printing `When I try to console.log(user.user)`

Comment: Actually ` user.user[0].email` also shows `user is null`

Comment: Is that data coming via an async operation? Coming from a remote place?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
return(
  <div>
   {user.user&&user.user.map(u=>
    <h3 key={u.id}>{u.email}</>
   )}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting it after checking user like this

```
if(user.user){
    console.log(user.user[0].email) ;   
    console.log(user.user[0].id) ;  
}
```

This also can be use as `{user.user && user.user[0].email}`